# OBS, other encoder than FFmpeg VAAPI H.264 and x264?

Tags: linux, intel-graphics, video-encoding, obs-studio

Linux + Intel HD 620. I can see only two options. If what I read on the web is correct, the GPU is capable of encoding H265 or VP9. Why can't I encode in those formats? Is this because OBS does not support them, or because some packages are missing?

[image]

Comment: Which OBS version?

Comment: [29.0.2-5 in Arch community repository](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/obs-studio/)

Comment: You should edit additional details into the question itself. More questions - what's the platform you're trying to stream on? Which codecs are available in recording section? H265 is not supported by some platforms, for instance Twitch, even if your card supports that.